# In Typescript, can a method of an instantiated object, when used by map(), access that object's properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, object, methods

I have a class that has a method I want to use via Typescript's array.map() functionality.  I've instantiated an object from that class and am using the method from that instantiated object.  Should that method, when used in map(), have access to the properties of that instantiated object?  From my testing, it seems that it does not.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve]? `array.map` isn't TypeScript functionality, it's JS.

Comment: i said typescript to be clear that i had classes that could be instantiated (i'm not sure you can do that in all versions of javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> From my testing, it seems that it does not.

Common mistake is poor `this`. Example that will fail:

```
class Foo {
  x = 123
  returnX() { return this.x; } 
}
const fail = [new Foo()].map(foo.returnX);
```

## Fix

Use arrow function:

```
class Foo {
  x = 123
  returnX = () => { return this.x; } 
}
const pass = [new Foo()].map(foo.returnX);
```

## More

- [Arrow functions typescript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html)
- A free video I did on `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the scope of this in functions vs arrow function. Arrow functions this will always be the instance of the object the function is attached to. In normal functions this is the object which the calling function is attached to

```
class MyClass {
  multiplyer = 2;

  x = [1,2,3].map(this.double);

  doubleArrow = val => this.multiplyer * val; // this is always what you expect it to be, the instance of this object

  y = [1,2,3].map(this.doubleArrow);

  double(val) {
    return this.multiplyer * val; // this will change depending on the function that calls it
  }
}
```